# xpages: how to build my own requiredValidator using java

Tags: java, validation, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I've built several custom validator beans and registered them through the database's faces-config. This is mostly working as expected.

I tried both methods that are described in [Jeremy Hodges blog post](http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=982B853206340272852578CB0066C499):

a) calling a managed bean through the control's `validator` attribute as in

```
validator="#{myBean.validate}"
```

b) binding the validate method to the control's `xp:validator` complex attribute as in

```
<xp:this.validators>
  <xp:validator validatorId="myValidator"></xp:validator>
</xp:validators>
```

Validation works as expected as long as the control to be validated contains a value; it's not firing at all if the control's value is `null`. This leads me to the conclusion that somehow a standard required validator (`xp:validateRequired`) must be invoked somehow differently from other validators. Question is: how can I get my customValidator to be called in a situation where a requiredValidator would be fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, requiredValidators have to be handled differently. Have you tried Sven Hasselbach's advice on his blog? http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=764

Also, Sven's answer on this quesstion about custom validators might be worth considering when creating validators [customValidator without requiredValidator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098964/customvalidator-without-requiredvalidator).

Comment: Great, that did it! Once again, many thanks to both @Sven and you